# C question with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I have a program question, here is the code.

```
int main()
{
int *p,*q;
p=(int*)1000;
printf("%d ",p);
q=(int*)2000;
printf("%d",q);
printf("%d",(p-q));
return 0;
}
```

But answer coming as

```
1000 
2000 
-250
```

I am unable to understand what happen with `p-q` and why answer came as `-250`?

Comment: Note that printing pointers with the `%d` format specifier invokes undefined behaviour. You can print `void*` with the `%p` format specifier, `printf("%p ", (void*)p);`, or you can cast the pointer to an integer type before printing, `printf("%" PRIdPTR " ", (intptr_t)p);`. For the pointer difference, `printf("%td ", (p-q));`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Correct but probably useless answer: `p - q` is equal to `(1000 - 2000) / (sizeof int)`.  For most C compiles, `sizeof int` is 4.

Potentially more useful answer: the effect of typecasts like `(int*) 1000` is undefined.  That code creates a pointer to an int *at address 1000*.  That address is probably invalid.  To create a pointer to an int with value 1000, write this:

```
int i = 1000;
int *p = &i;
```

Now `p` points to `i`, and `*p`, the value pointed to by `p`, is 1000.

Here is some correct code that may say what you meant:

```
int main() {
  int i = 1000;
  int j = 2000;

  int *p = &i;
  int *q = &j;

  printf("i = %d *p = %d\n", i, *p);
  printf("j = %d *q = %d\n", j, *q);
  printf("*p - *q = %d\n", *p - *q); 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you subtract two pointers, as long as they point into the same array, the result is the number of elements separating them.

On your platform, an int is 4 bytes. There are -250 elements between address 2000 and address 1000.

Since p and q don't both point to the same array, the result is undefined. You could get any result, including the one you expect.

Answer (score 0):

So much undefined behaviour in this program, the values printed are really quite immaterial.

Comment: How is it 7 people upvoted a -1 comment but the answer still has +1?

Answer (score 0):

`p` is a pointer variable, which can store only address of a `int` variable. But you are storing `1000` as an address, which is invalid. And then you are storing `2000` to the variable `q`.

Now you are doing pointer arithmatic `p-q`. Always pointer arithmatic will gives the output based on the size of the type of address. Which will work like `(p - q)/sizeof(type)`.

Consider if `p` and `q` are `char *` variable, then `p-q` will gives you the output as `-1000`

In your case `p` and `q` are `int *` variable, then `p-q` will gives you the output as `250` if size of `int` is 4 bytes. Execute this on the compiler where size of `int` is 2 bytes, you will get a result as `-500`.