# Some pointer clarification

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C question with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748249/c-question-with-pointers)

I need some help with pointers, specifically the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int *i, *j;

    i = (int *) 60;
    j = (int *) 40;
    printf("%d", i - j);

    return 0;
}
```

This code generates `10` as output. I just need to know what exactly `i - j` does here.

Answer (score 11):

`i` and `j` point to memory locations `60` and `40`, respectively.

What you're doing here is pointer subtraction.  If `i` and `j` were byte pointers (char *), `i-j` would be `20`, as one might expect.

However, with other pointers, it returns the number of **elements** between the two pointers.  On most systems, `(int *)60 - (int *)40` would be `5`, as there is room for five 4-byte integers in those twenty bytes.  Apparently, your platform has 16 bit integers.

Answer (score 3):

The program is probably supposed to print the pointer difference between `60` and `40`, cast to pointer to `int`. The pointer difference is the number of `int`s that would fit in the array from address `40` to address `60` (exclusive).

That said, the program violates the C standard. Pointer arithmetic is undefined except with pointers pointing into the same (`static`, automatic or `malloc`'d) array, and you cannot reliably print a pointer difference with `%d` (use `%td` instead).

Comment: There is more violation of the standard. In general arithmetic with pointers that do not point to valid objects is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

This is pointer arithmetic, the code `i - j` subtracts two *pointers to int*. Such arithmetic is aware of the data sizes involved, and so in this case will return the number of `ints` between the two addresses.

A result of `10` indicates that you're running this on a system with *2-byte* integers: 20 memory addresses between `i` and `j`, and your code prints `10`, so there are `10` 2-byte `ints` between the two addresses.

But on another system, with 4-byte integers, this would print `5`:  20 memory addresses between `i` and `j`, so there are `5` *4-byte* `ints` between the two addresses.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d",i-j); return 0;
```

both i and j are pointer to an integer.So they follow pointer arithematics.
As per  pointer mathematics pointer to an integer always shift sizeof(int).I
think you use gcc compiler where sizeof int is 4.So 60-40=20 but as unit  is 4 so out put is
5.

but if you use turbo c where sizeof int is 2.then out put is 10.

### NOTE

if pointers are included in some expression evaluation then they follow pointer arithematics.

Comment: Drise, that's no reason for a downvote. He might have started writing before the other was submitted.

Comment: @Cubic You can downvote for whatever reason you like. And the answer is still poorly written.

Comment: larsmans - not necessarily. Most compilers would use the word size of the architecture as the size of int, but I don't think this is actually a requirement.

Comment: @larsmans :-  for clarification about sizeof .The sizeof is a keyword and keywords use by compiler.so sizeof converted at the time of compilation not at run time.Just go through the keyword sizeof.....

Comment: @RajeshKumarSahoo: yes. And its value is determined by the processor architecture for which you're compiling.

Comment: @larsmans:[link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Implementation  just use this link for clarification.in c99 standard there is a provision for run-time sizeof evaluation only for variable length array.

Comment: @larsmans: I know of at least one system where it uses bitfield-like calulations to make `char` be 8 bits, when the smallest addressable size is actually 16 bits.  There's no reason it couldn't do strange stuff for `int` as well.  The C++ standard makes no references to the target architecture.  A compiler that made `int` 128 bits on the origional x86 would still be conforming.

Comment: @RajeshKumarSahoo: I stand corrected by the other posters. I wasn't claiming it's determined at runtime, though.

Answer (score -1):

`i` an `j` are the pointer to int variable, that means which is going to store virtual address of an int variable.

If we do any pointer arithmatic on this variable it will preform based on size of the type of variable which is pointing. For example `i++` will increase the value from `60` to `64` if size of int is 4 bytes.

So you are getting 10 for `i - j`, that means size of int is 2 in your environment. Always `i - j` will give you how much element(of type `int`) that can accomodate in that range.

So between 60 and 40, we can store 10 elements of type `int` if size of `int` is 2 bytes.

Comment: Why did you submit this answer 2.5 hours after all the others, and say practically the exact same thing?

Answer (score -3):

First, two integer pointers are declared which are called i and j. Note that their values are memory addresses to where pointers are stored, not integers themselves (the concept of a pointer).

Next, the pointers i & j are changed to 60 and 40, respectively. Now this represents a spot in memory and not the integers sixty and forty because i and j was never dereferenced.

Then it prints the memory address of i-j which will subtract that two memory addresses.

Comment: Pointer subtraction is a well defined operation in C.

Comment: This will always output 10 on his system because he specifically assigns the pointers. This is an example for pointer arithmetic, not for dynamic allocation.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that I did not explain myself clearly. Apologies. I meant that the subtraction would not yield any meaningful results in the given scenario.